# Selenium 2 C# WebDriverBackedSelenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Does the Selenium 2 C# library support using Selenium 1 commands? 
I know in java you could create a WebDriverBackedSelenium object and use Selenium 1 commands on it but I can't seem to find how to do it in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done but not sure if it has been released yet. If you get the latest code from [trunk](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout) and build it then you will be able to use it.